# node-fetch ignores query string with commander.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch, node-commander

I created a CLI with commander.js that I have published via npm. The CLI uses node-fetch to request data from an API. However, for some users of my CLI, node-fetch is ignoring the query string in my fetch URL.

My assumption is that the some users have an older version of node-fetch installed and it is using that version instead of the explicit version in my dependencies list in package.json.

If this is the reason, how can I ensure that the correct version of node-fetch is used with my CLI?

Are there any other reasons you can think of that would cause some environments to ignore the query string?

Answer (score 0):

To assert this problem you can write `tests`. Then execute those tests using different versions of `node-fetch` to see if that's really the problem.

A simpler way to solve it (assuming it is the real problem), could be to set the exact version of `node-fetch` that you want your users to install in your `package.json`, using npm's [versioning notation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies).

So, for example:

- `"1.0.0"` Must match version exactly
- `">1.0.0"` Must be greater than version
- `">=1.0.0"` Etc.